# How to avoid Hibernate and JDBC logging in log4j logger

Tags: java, logging, wildfly

I have done below all possible changes to avoid Hibernate and JDBC logging to logger ,but still i am getting below logs in my JBOSS application .

I do not want to log these Hibernate and JDBC logs to logger .

My changes in **log4j.properties** :

1.log4j.logger.org.hibernate=WARNING

2.log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=OFF

log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager=DEBUG

**Jave Code Changes**

```
  1. org.jboss.logging.Logger logger = org.jboss.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate");
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

    2. java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Logger Output :

Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[]])] after transaction
re-enabling autocommit
Releasing JDBC connection
Released JDBC connection
HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
Released JDBC connection

Comment: Please post your full log4.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.logging` is completely different from `log4j` so the code changes you made will have no effect on the log statements you are trying to suppress.

Instead, commenting out those lines should turn off logging for those components:

```
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate=WARNING
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=OFF
```

Comment: still its not working as i have commented those lines in log4j.properties file.log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/dctlog.log
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

Comment: Raise your root logger level from DEBUG to INFO: `log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, FILE`; oh and you should definitely paste your log4j.properties file in your question and NOT as a comment as you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Hibernate that is provided by the container logging will be configured by the logging subsystem and not your `log4j.properties` file.

You can use the follow CLI commands to turn off SQL logging and change Hibernate to only log at a warning level.

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.hibernate:add(level=WARN)
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.hibernate.SQL=OFF
```

As far as I know by default Hibernate does not log SQL statements. Check your `persistence.xml` as well to make sure you did not turn on logging of SQL statements there.

Comment: ,I am using hibernate only to get SeesionFactory object and running query using SQLQuery object like below.                                                     @Autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory;                                                                                                                       SQLQuery query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("");                         resultList = query.list();  i don't have any persistence.xml ,my hibernate.cfg.xml file is empty.i don't know where to change to block hibernate and sql logs in logger.